# calling a function in a function c++

Tags: c++, function, loops, syntax

I cant seem to figure this out. What I would like to do is declare three functions. One that takes user input of a value "balance". The other displays a menu. I would like to call these functions in "main" function and would like to bring the "balance" entered from function "balanceAcquired" with it.

Im new to c++ so my code may be sloppy but the errors Im getting are

error C4716: 'balanceAcquire': must return a value

error C4716: 'menu' : must return a value

error c4700: uninitialized local variable 'balance' used

```
// check book balancing program

//header files
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


int balanceAcquire(){

    float balance;          // balance entered by user

    // acquire balance

    cout << "check book balancing program \n\n";
    cout << "Enter the beginning balance: ";
    cin >> balance;
}



int menu(){

//menu

    cout << "Commands: \n";                     // commands
    cout << "C - process a check\n";            // process a check
    cout << "D - process a deposit\n";          // process a deposit
    cout << "E - End the program\n";            // end the program
}


int main(){

// define variables

    const float fee = .25;          // fee for transaction

    float check,                    // check amount
        deposit,                    // deposit amount
        balance;                    // balance amount

    char choice;                    // user entered choice
    float serviceCharges = 0;       // service charges amount tally

// initiate program

    balanceAcquire();
    menu();

    cout << "Enter transaction type: " << endl;     // ask for a choice
    cin >> choice;                                  // choice type

    switch (choice) {
        case 'c':
            cout << "Enter transaction amount: " << endl;   
            cin >> check;                           
            cout << "Processing check for" << check << endl;                        
            balance -= check; 
            cout << "Balance: " << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
            cout << "Service charge: $.25 for a check" << endl;                     
            serviceCharges += fee;                                                  
            cout << "Total service charges: " << serviceCharges << "\n\n";
            break;                                                                  

        case 'd':
            cout << "Enter transaction amount: " << endl;                           
            cin >> deposit;                                                         
            cout << "Processing deposit for" << deposit << endl;                    
            balance += deposit;                                                     
            cout << "Balance: " << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;              
            cout << "Total service charges: " << serviceCharges << "\n\n";  
            break;

        case 'e':
            cout << "Processing end of month" << endl;
            balance -= serviceCharges;
            cout << "Final Balance: $" << balance << endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

among other things the whole point of me trying to write it out this way was so I could return to "menu" to allow user to select more deposit or checks to be entered and at the end the receive there final balance minus transaction fees.

edit 1: formatting

Comment: Two counts of undefined behavior: no `return` in a function returning a value, using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: so I must set "balance" to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your code I conclude that you didn't grasp how function calls work. To put it in one sentence :

Function bodies can only interact with what is present in their signature, plus global state. They don't inherit anything implicitly from their caller.

For example, if you want `balanceAcquire()` to have an effect on the "outside", namely `main()`, you need to connect the pipes yourself.

**First way :**

```
int balanceAcquire() {
    float b;
    //...
    cin >> b;
    return b;
}
```

The function returns the value. On the outside, you get it back by using the function call expression as the value :

```
int main() {
    float balance;
    //...
    balance = balanceAcquire();
    // balance is set.
}
```

**Second way :**

```
void balanceAcquire(float &b) {
    //...
    cin >> b;
}
```

The function returns nothing (hence `void`), but gets `b` passed in by reference (`&`), which means that it has a direct access to a variable from the outside.

```
int main() {
    float balance;
    //...
    balanceAcquire(balance);
    // balance is set.
}
```

Comment: By reading your answer I conclude that you didn't grasp what function signatures are. They _do not_ include the function definition. (See `[defns.signature]` in your favourite ISO/IEC:14882 standard.)

Comment: _"Functions can only interact with what is present in their signature, plus global state."_

Comment: It's still not right! You're forgetting function-locals, data members, file-local `static`s, also absolutely any data whatsoever if accessed indirectly through a pointer....

Comment: Or it was declared locally. And the pointee may not be any of those things.

Comment: I could keep repeating _local variables_ and _data members_ to you but since I've already been doing that for 16 hours and you still haven't got it, I fail to see the point in continuing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Let's delete these pointless comments then, because I already answered that.

Comment: @quetin: *Sigh* No, you didn't. At this point I can only conclude that you're being deliberately obtuse. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm thinking the same, and it's pretty sad. Local variables don't matter : the function body doesn't *interact* with them because they're part of it. Anyway, since they're local they have no effect on the outside, by definition. Data members, they only happen in [methods/member functions], not functions. If you want to adapt the sentence to them, either add them explicitly to it, or consider that `this` is just another parameter. "File-locals" are at global scope, whatever their linkage is. Does this finally make sense ?

Comment: _"Local variables don't matter : the function body doesn't interact with them because they're part of it."_ What the heck

Comment: _"Data members, they only happen in [methods/member functions], not functions"_ Repeat after me: member functions are functions.

Comment: _"or consider that this is just another parameter"_ Which brings me to the third thing that you keep not getting: _the pointees are also data that you interact with_. `this` might be a parameter but the thing it points to is not, so clearly functions can do a lot more than you're claiming.

Comment: _"Does this finally make sense ?"_ Ok if you're going to be like that just because you don't understand something, I think we're done here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 4- Not a rhetorical question : English is not my mothertongue, and I'm obviously not clear enough (/making sense ?). 1- If I didn't fall in a language trap, "interact" means that you act with something *else*. You can't shake your own hand. 2- If there were no difference we wouldn't be arguing. Maybe "free-functions" would be better. 3- You still need to access them through said parameter, and wouldn't be able to do so weren't it there.

Comment: 3- I don't see how that changes anything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Even if you can access many things through a parameter, it's the parameter that gives you access in the first place. Thus, you can only access what is present in the function's signature. No ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well carry on then.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the errors.

> error C4716: 'balanceAcquire': must return a value

```
int balanceAcquire() {
*** <== declared to return int, no return in body
```

> error C4716: 'menu' : must return a value

```
int menu() {
*** <== declared to return int, no return in body
```

> error c4700: uninitialized local variable 'balance' used

In your main function, your code looks like:

```
float balance;
// [ snip ]
balance -= check; 
balance += deposit; 
balance -= serviceCharges;
```

That is undefined behavior, you have to initialize `balance` to some value before you read from it. Probably you want to assign it to the return value of `balanceAcquire()`, which should they return a `float`:

```
balance = balanceAcquire();
```

Comment: edit : if I add a return 0; to the end of the  balanceAcquire() function, it repeats itself twice before proceeding?

Comment: @kronis72 Why would you do `return 0;`? The point of the function is to acquire and return a balance from the user. So you should return that.

Comment: ok so I return balance.... sorry I havent really covered return values yet.. disregard previous comment... got it figured out thanks